# .txt date on HTML website, explode()

Tags: php

I've got a "data.txt" file with the following content:

```
One1:One2:One3:One4:One5:One6
Two1:Two2:Two3:Two4:Two5:Two6
Three1:Three2:Three3:Three4:Three5:Three6
```

Now I want to be able to take each data and put on a specific location of a htlm code. Each line for its own. So for the first line, it should look something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<head>
<body>
<h1>One2</h1>
<h2>One4 some other Text One5</h2>
<img src="One6.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Unforturtunately I don't have a clue how to do that with explode(). Can anybody help me out or does someone know a good and easy tutorial?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you showed us what you tried...

Comment: `each data` or `Each line` What do you want? Also do you only need to how to explode it or also how to grab it out of the file?

Comment: Know about `explode()`

Comment: Line 1: `One1:One2:One3:One4:One5:One6` / Line 2: `Two1:Two2:Two3:Two4:Two5:Two6` / Line 3: `Three1:Three2:Three3:Three4:Three5:Three6` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure if I got your question, but I think you want to first parse the data.txt line by line, THEN by the : delimiter.

```
$lines = file("data.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $split = explode(":", $line);
    $s1 = $split[0];
    $s2 = $split[1];
    $s3 = $split[2];

    echo '<h1>'.$s1.'</h1>'; 
    echo '<h2>'.$s2.' lorem ipsum</h2>'; 
    echo '<img src="'.$s3.'">';
}
```

Or would you like to output different content based on what line its currently reading from? Then something like:

```
$lines = file("data.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$n = count($lines);
for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)
{
    $split = explode(":", $lines[$i]);
    $s1 = $split[0];
    $s2 = $split[1];
    $s3 = $split[2];

    if($i === 0)
    {
        echo 'First line in data.txt<br>';
    }
    elseif($i === 1)
    {
        echo 'Second line in data.txt<br>';
    }
    elseif($i === 2)
    {
        echo 'Third line in data.txt<br>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'All the other lines (which are currently not existing)<br>';
    }
}
```

Just kind of guessing here, could need some more information to clarify the question :)